# Бесконтрольный рост используемой памяти в QWebEnginePage

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

При загрузке страницы социальной сети (или любой иной с аналогичным содержимым) при помощи `QWebEnginePage` происходит постепенный рост потребления памяти. Процесс браузера `QtWebEngineProcess` достигает лимита примерно в 1.8-2 Гб и отваливается с сегфолтом. При этом в консоль, примерно раз в секунду выводится сообщение:

> js: Uncaught (in promise) Error: The manifest specifies content that cannot be displayed on this browser/platform.

Минимально компилируемый код, воспроизводящий проблему, до безобразия прост:

```
QWebEnginePage *page = new QWebEnginePage(this);
page->load(QUrl("https://www.facebook.com/echomsk.ru"));
```

При этом, если к объекту класса страницы подключить объект класса её визуального представления, то проблема **не наблюдается**:

```
QWebEnginePage *page = new QWebEnginePage(this);
page->load(QUrl("https://www.facebook.com/echomsk.ru"));

QWebEngineView *view = new QWebEngineView(this);
view->setPage(page);
```

Симптомы абсолютно одинаковы как на Ubuntu 16.10 x64, так и на Windows 7 x64.

Версия Qt 5.8.0 x64

С чем может быть связана такая беда и что можно придумать такого, чтобы её с успехом ликвидировать?

[Багрепорт](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-60119)

Comment: Утечки памяти надо смотреть valgrind'ом, ну и попробовать другую версию Qt. Что-то ещё посоветовать тут сложно, имхо. Хотя можно ещё предложить запостить баг-репорт :)

Comment: @alexolut, вот этот минимальный пример из двух строк на чистом проекте (больше вообще ничего нет) запускает процесс браузера `QtWebEngineProcess.exe`, который в свою очередь (отчётливо видно в диспетчере задач) каждую секунду съедает ОЗУ от 10 до 50 Мб. Доходит примерно до 2 Гб и отваливается с сегфолтом. То есть не сам минимальный проект, а именно `QtWebEngineProcess.exe`. И только в том случае, если в минимальном проекте не используется `QWebEngineView`, чтобы вывести содержимое вебстраницы на экран. Пробовал ещё на Qt5.9.beta - поведение аналогичное.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению версия Qt 5.8.0 имеет свои небольшие особенности. Например, не корректно работает QNetworkAccessManager и иже с ним QNetworkRequest. Я так подозреваю, что при таком минимальном коде, утечка происходит в самом Qt. Такое уже наблюдалось с другими классами.

Лучший, наверное, вариант в данном случае - это воздержаться пока от перехода на новую версию и запускать с Qt 5.7.1. До выхода стабильного релиза.

Есть еще конечно решение - это расковырять исходники Qt, устранить проблемму, отписаться им, они увидят это, скажут - Вау) И будут все счастливы)

З.Ы. С определенного момента времени политика самого Qt поменялась - появились графики выхода версий и они.... ну впечатляют своей скоростью. Вот и торопятся ребята за желанием руководства. Может это и хорошо, а может и плохо, время покажет. Но баги есть и не мало.